# Download file in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, file, download

Hi I have a problem downloading a file from my ASP.NET web page.
I created the following code

```
 FileInfo hello = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath(@".\hello.zip"));
 Response.Clear();
 Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + hello.FullName);
 Response.WriteFile(hello.FullName);
 Response.Flush();
 Response.End();
```

When I place the above code in the click event of a button the code runs but the download does not actually start. When I move the same block of code in the page_load event everything works. Do you have any clue why this is happening??

Thanks
Sam

Comment: i've just tried it in my viusal studio and it works on button click and page_Load. maybe it's something else?

Comment: I would replace `hello.FullName` with `hello.Name` so you don't get any goofy filenames coming down to your client. I too have successfully created 3 examples of file download in Asp.NET, including Web Forms like your code sample, MVC (which takes only one line, easy), and a simple anchor tag with the href attribute set to the resource. Consider if you really need server code to deliver the zip file, and feel free to ask for my examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue. We are using Telerik UI controls and among which is an Ajax Manager. To fix the problem I found out that I have to write a javaScript function to disable Ajax on the button (thus causing a full page postback allowing the file to open in the browser window )I also had to add an entry in the Ajax Manager where the button should update itself.

Thanks